# Add Dictionaries Keys Values to Array [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, dictionary

Here is a sample of my data structure in **JavaScript**:

```
var list = [{"username":"admin1"}, {"username":"admin2"}, {"username":"admin3"}, 
{"username":"admin4"}, {"username":"admin5"}];
```

How can I add each "username" to a new array (`var result = []`)?

A sample of the final data structure would be:

```
var result = ["admin1", "admin2", "admin3", "admin4", "admin5"];
```

Thank you *

Comment: Loop it and create an new array having username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate an array by iterating over the elements.

```js
var list = [{"username":"admin1"}, {"username":"admin2"}, {"username":"admin3"}, 
{"username":"admin4"}, {"username":"admin5"}];

var res = list.map(function(o) {
  return o.username
});

console.log(res);
```

---

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
var list = [{"username":"admin1"}, {"username":"admin2"}, {"username":"admin3"}, 
{"username":"admin4"}, {"username":"admin5"}];

let res = list.map(o => o.username);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: With some ES6 goodness: `const res = list.map(o => o.username)`

Comment: Important: Do I have to import some script to use the Array#map method in AngularJS? The .map function is not recognized.

Comment: @Julia : check browser compatibility : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Julia :  are sure that it's an array?

Comment: My SQL server was shut down, so no data were returned --' thank you, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var list = [{"username":"admin1"}, {"username":"admin2"}, {"username":"admin3"}, 
{"username":"admin4"}, {"username":"admin5"}];
var array=[];

 for (var key in list) {
    let value = list[key];
    console.log(value.username);
    array.push(value.username);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```